# Google Desktop - Possible to create a gadget with a pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, google-gadget, google-desktop

I'm trying to write a kind of wrapper for arbitrary Google Desktop gadgets where I will display some information about a given gadget. I need a way to display this info that will work for every gadget. The easiest way, I figure, is to have a window pop up which will display the information separately. Is there any way to do this?

All I could find was the DetailsView. However, I could only add a detailsview if the original gadget doesn't have one. I also considered putting the info in the OptionsDialog, but again, the original gadget might be using it. Is there a way to just add an arbitrary pane and have it display?

Comment: hasn't google desktop been discontinued?

Comment: not sure, i asked this 2 years ago...

Comment: Ahh haha, strange, this came up as I was browsing. Sorry! :)